# Regular Expressions Aren't Working in Bulk File Renaming

Tags: regex, powershell, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm missing something with my use of regex, because my line works when I replace defined strings. I tried `\d` and `[0-9]`. What am I forgetting?

Original `FOOBAR_12345678-0001.csv`

Goal `12345678.csv`

```
get-childitem *.csv | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("FOOBAR_(\d{8})-\d{4}", "$1") }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
get-childitem *.csv | foreach { rename-item $_ ( $_.Name -replace 'FOOBAR_(\d{8})-\d{4}', '$1') }
```

Why:

1. I suspect the .Replace() method you were using doesn't take regexes.
2. I'm not 100% sure it's necessary but I've made the practice of using single quotes with powershell regexes in case there is any shell expansion shenanigans going on.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I was so stumped. Definitely going to stick to single quotes.